# Making HTML Inactive

Tags: html

I am trying to use JavaScript and the replace function in JavaScript to replace the spaces in a variable with "`<br />`". To clarify, I do not want a break, I want it to literally say "`<br />`". How would I make "`<br />`" invalid HTML?

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

This uses HTML "entities" for `<` and `>` ("less than" and "greater than")